# Can not upload apk on playstore second time

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, google-play-services

I have uploaded apk file few days back on playstore. after that I deleted my keystore and couldn't update that app again. Now I am trying to upload new app but playstore giving error

[image]

I tried to change package name in config.xlm but still not working?

what could be the issue playstore don't allow to delete previous app

Comment: try it first delete existing android platform from project.. then change package name from config.xml .. then add platform back..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simple, you need to have a different package name. It's mentioned right there in the screenshot you shared !

Comment: the screenshot proves you didnt ! recheck your app !